# Triangular indices for multidimensional arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

We know that `np.triu_indices` returns the indices of the triangular upper part of a matrix, an array with two dimensions.

What if one wants to create indices as in the following code?

```
indices = []
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        for k in range(j+1,n):
            indices.append([i,j,k])
```

in a num-pythonic way?

Comment: Have you looked at the code for `triu`?  It's probably Python, no compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can get a list of indexes that follow the logic of the code you put with

```
from itertools import combinations
ndim = 3 # number of dimensions
n = 5 # dimension's length (assuming equal length in each dimension)

indices = list(combinations(range(n), r=ndim)
```

or if you want to iterate over each position:

```
for i,j,k in combinations(range(n), r=ndim):
    # Do your cool stuff here
    pass
```

---

However, you referred to it as the triangular upper part of a multidimensional matrix. I'm not sure what's the definition of it, and trying to visualize the indexes you selected with your nested loops I can't figure it out... (I'm just curious now on if there's a deffinition for multidimensional triangular matrix :-P)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

a = zip(*indices)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(a[0], a[1], a[2])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

[image]
(I moved the view angle to try to show what positions are selected)