# Triangular indexing and choice of summation axis for multidimensional arrays / matrices

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm trying to solve a problem using multidimensional arrays, rather than resorting to `for` loops, in order to gain a performance boost, but am having trouble with the indexing.

I've tried various permutations using `np.newaxis`, but can't seem to achieve the following functionality.

**Problem:**

Part 1) Take an M x N x N array called `a`, and for each of the M square matrices, set the upper triangular matrix elements as their negative values.

Part 2) Sum all elements in each of the M matrices (of shape N X N), returning a 1D array with M elements. Let's call this array `b`.

**Attempted Solution**

Here is my MWP / attempt using loops (which does work, but I'd rather find a fully array/matrix-based approach

```
a = np.array(
      [[[  0,  1],
        [  5,  0]],

       [[ 0,  3],
        [ 2,  0]]])
```

Part 1):

```
triangular_upper_idx = np.triu_indices_from(a[0])
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i][triangular_upper_idx] *= -1
a
```

result:

```
array([[[ 0, -1],
        [ 5,  0]],

       [[ 0, -3],
        [ 2,  0]]])
```

Part 2):

```
b = np.zeros(len(a))
for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i] = np.sum(a[i])
b
```

result:

```
array([ 4., -1.])
```

Note:
I have seen a similar question on this topic ([Triangular indices for multidimensional arrays in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856137/triangular-indices-for-multidimensional-arrays-in-numpy)) but the solution there was nested for loops... I feel like numpy may offer a more efficient, clever array-based solution?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes numpy has the tools

```
r = 2

neg_uppr = np.triu(-np.ones((r,r)),1) + np.tril(np.ones((r,r)))
```

can't tell from your numerical example if you want the diagonal to be inverted too?  Then use `np.triu(-np.ones((r,r))) + np.tril(np.ones((r,r)),-1)`

```
neg_uppr
Out[23]: 
array([[ 1., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])

a = np.array(
      [[[  0,  1],
        [  5,  0]],

       [[ 0,  3],
        [ 2,  0]]])
```

its fast to use the builtin element-wise arithmetic

```
a = a * neg_uppr

a
Out[26]: 
array([[[ 0., -1.],
        [ 5.,  0.]],

       [[ 0., -3.],
        [ 2.,  0.]]])
```

you can specify axes to sum over:

```
np.sum(a, (1,2))
Out[27]: array([ 4., -1.])
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I didn't realise np.sum could have an array argument for its axis. That works great.